# Tweepy Duplicates

Tags: python, tweepy

Is there a way to get the max page numbers before running:

```
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.users_search, searchterm).pages():
    # page is a list of users
    process_page(page)
```

Right now I'm having this problem where either I set the number of pages or items to N and either not grab everyone, or there not being enough people and grabbing everyone and having many duplicates. This seems inefficient. If I don't put N number of pages or items it keeps looping until 52 which I believe is the max number of twitter pages.

This also happens when you're searching someone's friends/followers. And also effects the rate limiting because I'm not grabbing the correct number of pages so I'm wasting more calls.

Comment: I don't see what "N" you mean. When iterating over whatever `pages()` returns, you will visit every enty exactly one time (except it it returned multible times by the iterator for whatever reason). Could you give more of your code so we can see why and when you need to know the number of pages?

Comment: By N i just mean any number of pages. If you follow the documentation on tweepy page and the way they do it. It just keeps grabbing pages not the "correct number" of pages. So if a searchterm has 3 pages worth of users I just want 3 pages. But tweepy keeps grabbing pages until page 52.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how the cursor works - to my knowledge (and from a decent amount of experience working in tweepy) it absolutely returns the "correct number" of pages.

Comment: I never worked with tweepy but I know that `for page in ...pages()` will iterate over exactly every page returned and `pages()` returnes whatever it is designed for - not what you want it to. If you get more pages than you want, filter them, use another method to get them or specify the correct parameters.
If you really know what pages you want, it should be easy to filter them, if you don't know that, you can just use every page returned.